# How to use "svn ls svn://XXXX:XXXX/foo/bar/foobar" to show whole file path?

Tags: svn

```
svn ls svn://XXXX:XXXX/foo/bar/foobar svn://XXXX:XXXX/bar/foo/foobar -v
```

I know the command above can display these info:

```
58767 XXXX         511 March 17 11:36 foobar
58768 XXXX         512 March 17 11:46 foobar
```

But I want to display whole file path like this to discriminate them:

```
58767 XXXX         511 March 17 11:36 /foo/bar/foobar
58768 XXXX         512 March 17 11:46 /bar/foo/foobar
```

Can it come true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other indirect solution is using --xml instead of -v.

```
svn ls svn://XXXX:XXXX/foo/bar/foobar svn://XXXX:XXXX/bar/foo/foobar --xml
```

It will display whole file paths like these:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lists>
<list
   path="svn://XXXX:XXXX/foo/bar/foobar">
<entry
   kind="file">
<name>foobar</name>
<size>511</size>
<commit
   revision="58767">
<author>XXXX</author>
<date>2019-03-17T11:36:19.927875Z</date>
</commit>
</entry>
</list>
<list
   path="svn://XXXX:XXXX/bar/foo/foobar">
<entry
   kind="file">
<name>foobar</name>
<size>512</size>
<commit
   revision="58768">
<author>XXXX</author>
<date>2019-03-17T11:46:19.237875Z</date>
</commit>
</entry>
</list>
</lists>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [SVN documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.list.html), there is no option to get what you want directly.

Indirect solutions:

- If it is not too slow you can do `svn ls svn://XXXX:XXXX/ -v | grep foobar`
- Or if it is too slow, do two separate calls of `svn ls` with just the one file you want, and echo them separately, eventually using `sed` or `awk` if you need exactly the formatting stated in the question.

Comment: I found other solutions in the [SVN documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.list.html).Just using --xml instead of -v.Thanks.